# Using values from a form input to determine if they are above a certain age

Tags: javascript

How would I write a program that takes in the values from an html form, calculate the age of the user and determine if they can visit the website if they are above the specified age?

My initial thought process was to get the values from the input form once the button is clicked. Compare that value with the today's date, and if that value is below a specified age, the user will be directed to different website.

Here is what I have now.

```js
// get values
var userMonth = document.getElementById('userMonth');
var userDay = document.getElementById('userDay');
var userYear = document.getElementById('userYear');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('btnCheckBday');

// when the button is clicked
submitButton.addEventListener("click", calcBirthDate);

// calculating birthday
function calcBirthDate() {
  // get values from user info
  month = userMonth.value;
  day = userDay.value;
  year = userYear.value;

  today = new Date();
  birthday = new Date(year, month, day);
  oldEnough = today - birthday;

  if (oldEnough >= 21) {
    console.log("You are older than 21");
  } else {
    console.log("You are below the age of 21");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="container form-contain">
    <!-- name input -->
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="name" class="col-2 col-form-label" id="label-name">Full Name</label>
      <div class="col-10">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="input-name">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="from-group row">

      <!-- month -->
      <label for="month" class="col-2 col-form-label" id="label-year">Month:</label>
      <div class="col-2">
        <input type="number" name="month" class="form-control" id="userMonth">
      </div>

      <!-- Day -->
      <label for="day" class="col-2 col-form-label" id="label-year">Day</label>
      <div class="col-2">
        <input type="number" name="day" class="form-control" id="userDay">
      </div>

      <!-- Year -->
      <label for="year" class="col-2 col-form-label" id="label-year">Year</label>
      <div class="col-2">
        <input type="number" name="year" class="form-control" id="userYear">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnCheckBday" value="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What's happening when you click on the submit button? Any errors or output to the console?

Comment: your code looks fine whats the error? or is it not running at all?

Comment: naw, there are no errors in the console. But i did notice that once its clicked, it prints to the console for a split second. Also, if I put a date that is clearly older than 21, it still leads to the else block "You are below age of 21". I think it has to do with reading the values as a string type compared to actual int/float types

Comment: maybe pass the event to your handler and prevent the default behavior which is submitting the form?

Comment: So from the sounds of it, the page is being reloaded. You can try changing the event listener line to `submitButton.addEventListener("click", calcBirthDate(event));` to pass in the click event. Then in your `calcBirthDate` function, put `event.preventDefault();` at the beginning of the function. Be sure to change the declaration of the `calcBirthDate` function to accept an `event` as a parameter.

Comment: hmm, so i tried that and now i'm getting an uncaught typeError. Why does it think that event being passed in is equal to null ?

Comment: @FanonX, I think everybody told you the solution most common thing about the problem (the result is showing for a split second). But your logic is also flawed, please check my answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `button` is interpreted as a submit button which submits the `form`. To prevent this, change the `button` type to "button" or use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from submitting if the user is not old enough.

Also, subtracting the two dates will not give the number of years between them, it is equivalent to doing `date2.getTime()-date1.getTime()`.

```js
// get values
var userMonth = document.getElementById('userMonth');
var userDay = document.getElementById('userDay');
var userYear = document.getElementById('userYear');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('btnCheckBday');

// when the button is clicked
submitButton.addEventListener("click", calcBirthDate);

// calculating birthday
function calcBirthDate() {
  var event = arguments[0];
  event.preventDefault();//call this anywhere to prevent form submission
  // get values from user info
  month = userMonth.value;
  day = userDay.value;
  year = userYear.value;

  today = new Date();
  birthday = new Date(year, month-1, day);
        var y1 = today.getFullYear();
        var m1 = today.getMonth();
        var d1 = today.getDate();
        var y2 = birthday.getFullYear();
        var m2 = birthday.getMonth();
        var d2 = birthday.getDate();
        var diff = y1 - y2;
        if (m2 > m1) diff--;
        else {
            if (m2 == m1) {
                if (d2 > d1) diff--;
            }
        }
        oldEnough = diff;
  if (oldEnough >= 21) {
    console.log("You are older than 21");
  } else {
    console.log("You are below the age of 21");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="container form-contain">
    <!-- name input -->
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="name" class="col-2 col-form-label" id="label-name">Full Name</label>
      <div class="col-10">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="input-name">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="from-group row">

      <!-- month -->
      <label for="month" class="col-2 col-form-label" id="label-year">Month:</label>
      <div class="col-2">
        <input type="number" name="month" class="form-control" id="userMonth">
      </div>

      <!-- Day -->
      <label for="day" class="col-2 col-form-label" id="label-year">Day</label>
      <div class="col-2">
        <input type="number" name="day" class="form-control" id="userDay">
      </div>

      <!-- Year -->
      <label for="year" class="col-2 col-form-label" id="label-year">Year</label>
      <div class="col-2">
        <input type="number" name="year" class="form-control" id="userYear">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnCheckBday" value="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, I still want the form to submit whether the user is old enough or not. So, from where I am now, I believe there is either an error in the logic of the code or with how it's reading the values as a string instead of integers. When I test for a date that is below 21 years old, it still prints out you are above 21 years old.

Comment: logic is flawed, try putting date of yesterday

Comment: @RaghavGarg I didn't notice that. Fixed it!

Comment: @FanonX I have fixed the logic.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the browser to perform usual task on form submission.

You birthday calculation logic is also flawed, `oldEnough = today - birthday` will give you epoch time(millisecond from 1970) which will always be greater than `21`. You can do something like shown below.

```js
// get values
var userMonth = document.getElementById('userMonth');
var userDay = document.getElementById('userDay');
var userYear = document.getElementById('userYear');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('btnCheckBday');

// when the button is clicked
submitButton.addEventListener("click", calcBirthDate);

// calculating birthday
function calcBirthDate(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // get values from user info
  month = userMonth.value;
  day = userDay.value;
  year = userYear.value;

  today = new Date();
  oldEnough = new Date();
  oldEnough.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() - 21)
  birthday = new Date(year, month, day);

  console.log(birthday)
  console.log(oldEnough)

  if (birthday < oldEnough) {
    console.log("You are older than 21");
  } else {
    console.log("You are below the age of 21");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="container form-contain">
    <!-- name input -->
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="name" class="col-2 col-form-label" id="label-name">Full Name</label>
      <div class="col-10">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="input-name">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="from-group row">

      <!-- month -->
      <label for="month" class="col-2 col-form-label" id="label-year">Month:</label>
      <div class="col-2">
        <input type="number" name="month" class="form-control" id="userMonth">
      </div>

      <!-- Day -->
      <label for="day" class="col-2 col-form-label" id="label-year">Day</label>
      <div class="col-2">
        <input type="number" name="day" class="form-control" id="userDay">
      </div>

      <!-- Year -->
      <label for="year" class="col-2 col-form-label" id="label-year">Year</label>
      <div class="col-2">
        <input type="number" name="year" class="form-control" id="userYear">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnCheckBday" value="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, awesome that what it was. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @FanonX do `month = userMonth.value - 1;` instead of `month = userMonth.value;`

Answer (score 0):

Just little updated of your code and it will show you correct answer about your age, please update it for your needs.

```js
// get values
var userMonth = document.getElementById('userMonth');
var userDay = document.getElementById('userDay');
var userYear = document.getElementById('userYear');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('btnCheckBday');

// when the button is clicked
submitButton.addEventListener("click", calcBirthDate);

// calculating birthday
function calcBirthDate() {
  // get values from user info
  month = userMonth.value;
  day = userDay.value;
  year = userYear.value;

  today = new Date();
  birthday = new Date(year+ "-"+month+"-"+ day);
  birthdayFormated = moment(birthday, "YYYY-MM-DD")
  oldEnough = today - birthdayFormated;

console.log("oldEnough "+oldEnough);

var today21 = today.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() - 21);
console.log("21 "+today21);

  if (new Date(oldEnough) >= new Date(today21)) {
    console.log("You are older than 21");
  } else {
    console.log("You are below the age of 21");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container form-contain">
    <!-- name input -->
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="name" class="col-2 col-form-label" id="label-name">Full Name</label>
      <div class="col-10">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="input-name">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="from-group row">

      <!-- month -->
      <label for="month" class="col-2 col-form-label" id="label-year">Month:</label>
      <div class="col-2">
        <input type="number" name="month" class="form-control" id="userMonth">
      </div>

      <!-- Day -->
      <label for="day" class="col-2 col-form-label" id="label-year">Day</label>
      <div class="col-2">
        <input type="number" name="day" class="form-control" id="userDay">
      </div>

      <!-- Year -->
      <label for="year" class="col-2 col-form-label" id="label-year">Year</label>
      <div class="col-2">
        <input type="number" name="year" class="form-control" id="userYear">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnCheckBday" value="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```